# How to adjust the IP network segment of the k8s cluster deployed by kind

Tags: kubernetes, kind

Deploy kubevela using the kind cluster, but the deployed pod network segments all start with 10.24. I want to switch to 172.16. How should I configure it, my friends？

[my pods ip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjvs5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [documentation](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/configuration/#pod-subnet)

> You can configure the subnet used for pod IPs by setting

So create file eg `config.yaml` with following content:

```yaml
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
networking:
  podSubnet: "172.16.0.0/16"
```

Use this file while creating cluster

```
kind create cluster --config config.yaml
```

Comment: thk a! I found it